# d3.js - add rectangle background to filtered elements

Tags: d3.js

I try to add a background rectangle for all filtered elements. the idea is add all filtered element into g element then use BBox of g element to draw the rectangle.

Two issues need help:

1. The top and bottom looks like cutted.
2. rectangle position has shift back half the width.(before add the rectangle, it's good)

```js
tree_demo()
function tree_demo() {
  tree(
    {name:'AAAA',children:[
      {name: "BBBB", children: [{name:'CCCC'}]},
      {name: "DDDD", children: [{name: "EEEE"}]},
      {name: "FFFF", children: [{name: "GGGG"}]},
      {name: "HHHH", children: [{name: "IIII"}]},
      {name: "JJJJ", children: [{name: "KKKK"}]},
      {name: "LLLL", children: [{name: "MMMM"}]},
    ]}
  );

  function add_defs(svg) {
    var col = 'black'
    var path = ['M',6,4,'L',1,2,1,6,'z'].join(' ')
    svg
      .append('defs')
      .append('marker')
      .attr('id', 'arr1')
      .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, 8, 8])
      .attr('refX', 7)
      .attr('refY', 4)
      .attr('markerWidth', 8)
      .attr('markerHeight', 8)
      .attr('orient', 'auto-start-reverse')
      .append('path')
      .attr('d',path)
      .attr('stroke', col)
      .attr('fill','black')

    path = ['M',10,0,10,6,2,2,2,10,10,6,10,12].join(' ')
    svg
      .append('defs')
      .append('marker')
      .attr('id', 'arr2')
      .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, 12, 12])
      .attr('refX', 10)
      .attr('refY', 6)
      .attr('markerWidth', 12)
      .attr('markerHeight', 12)
      .attr('orient', 'auto-start-reverse')
      .append('path')
      .attr('d',path)
      .attr('stroke', col)
      .attr('fill','black')

    path = ['M',10,6,2,2,3,6,2,10,'z'].join(' ')
    svg
      .append('defs')
      .append('marker')
      .attr('id', 'arr3')
      .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, 12, 12])
      .attr('refX', 10)
      .attr('refY', 6)
      .attr('markerWidth', 12)
      .attr('markerHeight', 12)
      .attr('orient', 'auto-start-reverse')
      .append('path')
      .attr('d',path)
      .attr('stroke', col)
      .attr('fill','black')

    path = ['M',10,0,10,12,'M',9,6,2,2,4,6,2,10,'z'].join(' ')
    svg
      .append('defs')
      .append('marker')
      .attr('id', 'arr4')
      .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, 12, 12])
      .attr('refX', 10)
      .attr('refY', 6)
      .attr('markerWidth', 12)
      .attr('markerHeight', 12)
      .attr('orient', 'auto-start-reverse')
      .append('path')
      .attr('d',path)
      .attr('stroke', col)
      .attr('fill','black')  
  }
  function tree(root) {
    var width = 400
    var height = 160
    var step = 50
    var margin = {top: 0, right: 40, bottom: 0, left: 60}

    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height,200])
    var node = treemap(d3.hierarchy(root))

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

    add_defs(svg)
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var nodes = treemap(d3.hierarchy(root))
    var links = treemap(nodes).links()
    
    var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data([nodes])
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var link = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d) { return links; })
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr('stroke','black')
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arr1)')

    var node = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(function(d) { return nodes; })
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")

    var rects = node.append("rect")
    .attr('fill-opacity',0.3)
    .attr('fill',(d,i) => {
      var c = 'none'
      if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 7 || i == 8) {
        c = color(1)
      }else if (i == 3||i==4||i==9||i==10) {
        c = color(2)
      }else if(i==5||i==6||i==11||i==12) {
        c = color(3)
      }
      return c
    })
    
    var mw = 100
    var x = 40
    var dist = [0,mw+2*x,mw+x,mw+x,mw+x,mw+x]
    var loc = []
    dist.map((d,i) => {
      if (i>0) {
        const [e] = loc.slice(-1)
        d += e
      }
      loc.push(d)
    })

    var txt = node.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr('font-size',12)
    .text(function(d) { 
      return d.data.type == 'hidden'?'':d.data.name; 
    })
    .each(function(d,i,n) { 
      d.width = Math.max(mw, this.getComputedTextLength() + 10); 
      d.height=20
      if (d.data.type == 'hidden') {
        d.width = 0
        d.height = 0
      }
      d.y = loc[d.depth]
    })
    .attr('x',d => {
      return d.y
    })
    .attr('y', d => d.x)

    node.filter(function(d) { return "join" in d.data; }).insert("path", "text")
      .attr("class", "join");

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.data.type; })
    .attr('x',d => d.y)
    .attr('y',d => d.x)

    var x = node.select("rect")
      .attr('stroke','black')
    .attr('x', d => d.y - d.width/2)
    .attr('y', d => d.x - d.height/2)
      .attr("ry", 0)
      .attr("rx", 0)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
    
    const zagzag = (d) => {
      let from = d.source
      let to = d.target
      let dx = to.y - from.y;
      let dy = to.x - from.x;
      if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
        let mx,my,nx,ny,sx,sy
        sx = (dx>0)?1:-1
        sy = (dy>0)?1:-1
        mx = from.y + from.width/2*sx
        my = from.x
        nx = to.y - to.width/2*sx
        ny = to.x
        dx = nx - mx;
        dy = ny - my;

        return `M ${mx},${my} l ${dx/2},0 0,${dy} ${dx/2},0 `;
      }else{//vertical
        let mx,my,nx,ny,sx,sy
        sx = (dx>0)?1:-1
        sy = (dy>0)?1:-1
        mx = from.y 
        my = from.x + from.height/2*sy
        nx = to.y
        ny = to.x - to.height/2*sy
        dx = nx - mx;
        dy = ny - my;
        return `M ${mx},${my} l 0,${dy/2} ${dx},0 0,${dy/2}`; 
      }
    };

    node.select(".join")
      .attr("d",d => zagzag(d) );

    svg.selectAll(".link path")
      .attr("d", d => zagzag(d));  
    
    // debug start
    var g1 = svg.append('g')
    x.filter((d,i) => i == 1||i==2||i==7||i==8)
    .each((d,i,n) => {
      g1.append(() => n[i])
    })
    
    var e = 5
    var box = g1.node().getBBox()
    svg.insert('rect','.nodes')
    .attr('stroke','black')
    .attr('fill','green')
    .attr('fill-opacity',.4)
    .attr('x',box.x-e)
    .attr('y',box.y-e)
    .attr('width',box.width+2*e)
    .attr('height',box.height+2*e)
    //debug end
    return svg;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```